# Is it possible to weld frames after the plant is finalised?

Tags: drake

I am trying to simulate rigid grasps between two robots and an object. Once both the robots approach the object and grasp it, is it possible to weld the frames of the end-effectors and the object, thereby eliminating any relative motion between them?

I require this since I intend to apply external forces on the object by a 3rd robot without having the grasp released by the first two robots.

I have tried to have maximum grasping torques, but the object still slides away when a large external force is applied.

[image: 2 Robots next to a plate]
Post Grasp, which is where I want to weld frames
[image: Both robots holding the plate]

The object is released when a 3rd robot collides, which I would like to avoid.
[image: Only one robot holds the plate]

Comment: I upvoted this question solely on the basis of its non-sequitur question title.